# Where can I locate source code of Drupal 1.0 or earlier version?

Tags: files

As for learning purposes, as I am developing my own micro-CMS (well, in fact a femto-CMS) in PHP + MySQL, I would like to locate the earliest possible version of the source code of Drupal. In Drupal.org I can only locate from version 4.x and above, I would like to find 1.0 or even an earlier beta version.